# Error while Converting specific date time to Sydney date using c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, timezone

Using below code I am trying to convert specific date time to Sydney date time.

```
string datetime = "20200424-04:09:42.145";
datetime  = datetime.Replace("-", " ").Insert(4, "-").Insert(7, "-");
TimeZoneInfo dest = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");
TimeZoneInfo src = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Greenwich Standard Time");
DateTime convertTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(datetime), src);
DateTime transactTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(convertTime, dest.Id);
```

Getting output invalid format - 4/24/2020  2:09:42 PM.145

System format date format dd/mm/yyyy and time in 24 hours

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- That input format is non-standard and a bit strange.  If you can change wherever it is constructed, that would be a better approach.  In the meantime, I suggest you parse it with  `DateTime.ParseExact` instead of replacing characters to get `Convert.ToDateTime` to recognize it.
- `Greenwich Standard Time` is the local time zone identifier for Monrovia (Liberia) and Reykjavik (Iceland) (and a few others).  I suspect you are actually trying to convert from GMT/UTC to Sydney time.  If so, you only need one conversion function - `ConvertTimeFromUtc`.
- You say you're getting invalid output format, but you don't show how you create that.  I assume you are doing something like `Console.WriteLine(transactTime)`, or just putting `transactTime` in some other place that converts it to a string.  When doing so, it will use the general format controlled by the current culture. (See the `Remarks` section in [the `DateTime.ToString` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring#System_DateTime_ToString).)
- It sounds like instead you would like a specific format, which you can get by specifying the desired output in the `ToString` method.  You can either specify a [standard format token](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) (usually used with the current culture), or your own [custom formatting tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) (usually used with the `InvariantCulture`).

A complete example illustrating the above points:

```
// Parse the input string to a DateTime, from a given format
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("20200424-04:09:42.145", "yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// Convert the datetime from UTC to Sydney time
TimeZoneInfo dest = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime transactTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt, dest);

// Create and output the string you want to output, in a specific format
string output = transactTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(output);

// Output:  "2020-04-24 14:09:42.145"
```

([Working .NET Fiddle here.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/81Dshl))